# Separating networks with limited access between

Tags: networking, vpn, vlan, subnet

I am trying to understand networks better and to help me learn I am working on a home project where I want to setup two networks, let's call them Client and Server, on the same geographic location. (Both networks get Internet from one single WAN, since I was not able to acquire multiple IPs from my ISP.) The two networks should be separated from each other, meaning I want to prevent malware or other threats from spreading across networks.

That being said, I am still trying to allow for a specific client to be able to periodically manage the servers from the client network.

I could of course switch the client between the networks physically, but it seems messy. My thought was to create a VPN tunnel instead, but I was curious if there are other/better options.

With three routers and some switches at my disposal, my questions are

1. Is subnetting or VLANs the better option to separate the networks? I've read a lot on both lately but can't decide on what would be best for this scenario.
2. Is VPN the most secure way for a client to access the server network, or would allowing it to access both networks all the time be just as secure?
3. Does the routers need to have a separate IP from it's parent router or is the gateway IP enough?
4. Do I really need three routers, or would it be enough with just one?

I have linked an image below to clarify my intended setup. Please let me know if this question is too in-depth for this forum. I am more than happy to learn on my own but need some pointers on where to start looking.

[Intended Network Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgADU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is subnetting or VLANs the better option to separate the networks? I've read a lot on both lately but can't decide on what would be best for this scenario.

Subnets is *logical* division of networks. It works on layer 3; different IP networks cannot communicate directly with eachother, but must go through a router.

You can have multiple subnets in use on the same physical segment if you want.

VLAN's is *physical* separation. It splits the network at the Layer 2 level, so no packets can flow from VLAN 1 to VLAN 2, without some device that sits in both VLANs.

Very often a combination is appropriate, where a subnet matches a vlan, so that you have a 1:1-mapping between subnets and physical broadcast domains, but this is not a *technical* requirement.

> Is VPN the most secure way for a client to access the server network, or would allowing it to access both networks all the time be just as secure?

VPN is a technique to transport packets securely over a unsecure network. Nothing more, nothing less. Depending on your threat model, using TLS and the Internet may be secure enough and far easier to deploy.

> Does the routers need to have a separate IP from it's parent router or is the gateway IP enough?

???

> Do I really need three routers, or would it be enough with just one?

Get a old computer with at least two NIC's. Install pfsense. Get a VLAN capable switch. Start playing. For added learning, add a second computer with pfsense, and set up a third subnet. Add routes between the networks. Deploy a dynamic routing protocol, such as OSPF.

Comment: Thank you for providing a very comprehensible answer! 

Regarding VPN, I understand the purpose, but I thought since it's often used to enable traffic from one network to another that I could use it to allow one client to access the server network. Am I incorrect in that it would be a solution to my second question?

Comment: My third question was mainly due to me chosing to setup a separate subnet for granting both networks internet access (172.16.1.0). I was thinking if I could skip this and just allow the parent router to grant internet access directly via each respective subnet.

Comment: Anyway, I will look into pfsense and play around. Will I need a separate client for this or will I be able to accomplish the same thing with modern routers?

Comment: VPN is for connecting networks that doesn't talk directly. It doesn't *really* make much sense if you control the physical network, like you do in your scenario. PFSense is a operating system that run on normal computers. Most SOHO routers is a piece of crap with outdated software and hides all kinds of configuration away from the user. An altenative to pfsense would be e.g. Edgerouter series, or Vyetta (also installs on a PC). If you have access to *real* routers from e.g. Cisco or Juniper, they're excellent, but somewhat expensive...

Comment: pfsense is a great compromise; it allows you to configure a lot of details, yet allows you to skip some nitty-gritty details, and it has a fairly large and well established user base. And it runs on almost any old computer, or in a VM, so you can get started quite cheaply.

Comment: Funny you should mention it, I actually bought an Unifi Edgerouter X and a Dream Machine Pro just for this project.


I understand that VPN makes less sense, but if I were to permanently allow communication between the networks, wouldn't that mean that potential malware could spread from the client network to the server network? I want to be able to manage the server network without exposing it to any risks.

Comment: Set up sensible firewall rules. A VPN doesn't really change that; firewall rules does.